# Apache deny/allow in vhost config and in .htaccess, which takes priority

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf

If I specify a `Deny from xx.xx.xx.xx` Directive in a `<Directory /var/www/html/test-directory/></Directory>` block in an Apache vhost configuration.
Then specify a different `Deny from yy.yy.yy.yy` in a `.htaccess` file in the same directory, which comes out on top?

It's my understanding that `.htaccess` should always take priority but in the case of Deny/Allow directives with different IP addresses, will the directives merge?
So both xx.xx.xx.xx and yy.yy.yy.yy are denied?

Or will one override the other?
I will do some tests later but I just wondered if anyone knew what should happen theoretically.

Comment: Your question will be a lot more useful once you've done the tests. You can answer your own question later on when you do your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying any number of `Deny` directives works just fine; all are applied.  However, they can be overridden by an `Allow` if you've set `Order Deny,Allow`.

If you have concerns about the access you're allowing, you should provide a more complete look at your configuration and an explanation of what you're looking to achieve so that we're able to assist.

Comment: I can confirm that the directives from httpd.conf and .htaccess are cascaded/merged in the case of `Deny` and `Allow` directives and that .htaccess does take priority. The problem I had was an `AllowOverride None` which initially prevented me from confirming this myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can put in these files is determined by the AllowOverride directive. This directive specifies, in categories, what directives will be honored if they are found in a .htaccess file.

I have copied this sentence from [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html), where is explained well how works .htaccess.